# Map SXA multi site to single domain with different ports

Tags: sxa, multisite, iis

Is there any way to attach two SXA sites from one Sitecore instance (IIS instance) to different port number of one domain name? For example:

- http://abc.com is on port 80 and pointing to one sxa site.
- http://abc.com:4502 is on port 4502 and pointing to other sxa site.

I tried by:

- Added new binding with port 4502 in IIS
- Added host name as ABC.com:4502 in sxa site manager

But when I am trying to access http://ABC.com:4502 then it's rendering default site which are on port 80 i.e. http://ABC.com.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. When we hit "ABC.com:4502" in browser. it try to find "ABC.com" host name only without port number in sxa site manager and not considering "ABC.com:4502". it seems "ABC.com:4502" is invalid entry in sxa site manager. so is there any configuration that can make it valid entry or any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore has the ability to define port within the  node for it's sites.

While SXA does not have an explicit entry to put the port in, the "Site definition" item is the SXA's equivalent of this and has an ability to provide those additional properties even if the SXA team wasn't aware of a property that should be there.

The following screenshot should give you the idea how:

[image: How to define site port in SXA]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Able to access 02 sxa sites on same domain name with different ports:
1. Added the different binding in IIS:
    abc.com with port 80
    abc.com with port 4502
2. Go to SXA site manager:
    For Site1 add the host name as "abc.com"
    For Site2 add the host name as "abc.com" and add the other properties as "port" with value 4502
3. Publish both Sites entries in SXA site manager

4  With the above settings able to access sites:
    Site1 -> http://abc.com
    Site2 -> http://abc.com:4502

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for the Minicart links in Commerce Accelerator.

Comment: Can confirm with DotPeek that Commerce Experience Accelerator class Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.UrlManager.StorefrontUrlManager does not take port number into account. I am reporting as a bug to Sitecore Support.